# Install apk from launcher error - Android 11

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to instal an apk from a java launcher (the apk is in download folder) but the logs return me: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Download/apk_to_install.apk`

This is my current code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="com.x.y.provider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
     android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
     android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="download" path="Download/"/>
</paths>
```

Activity code:

```
  File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath(), "apk_to_install.apk");
 installApk(this, apkFile);



  public static void installApk(Context context, File apkFile) {

        if (apkFile.exists()) {
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.x.y.provider", apkFile);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```